# If/Then Logic - Based on What Letter a Name Starts With

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create the following logic in Excel:

**Column B:**
If Last Name starts with A through J, THEN Column A = Project Manager A 
If Last Name starts with K through N, THEN Column A = Project Manager B

And so forth.

I have created an "Alphabet" tab to reference the alphabet.

[image]

[image]

**Second Part**: 
[image]

Comment: use left() to get the first character then vlookup() or match() & index() to find it in a list and bring back the result you want.

Comment: please show mocked up examples of how the names look

Comment: I concur with @SolarMike. My initial thought was to use the UNICODE() function to convert the letters to numbers, A-J becomes between 65 and 74 but I think the Lookup is a more versatile and easier to implement solutions. If you use UNICODE() remember that it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:
[image]

=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,1),$E$1:$F$9,2,0)

Do make sure the table in columns E & F have all the alphabet, also if the project managers change it is easy to edit.

And if some of the names start lower case then this will work:

[image]

Comment: You only need the three `A`, `K`, and `O` as long as they are alphabetical in the list you can use `TRUE` as the forth criterion and it will find the relative match.

Comment: @Solar Mike

Thank you for your speedy help! I just updated my question. Can you please explain your formulas using the columns that I posted? I'm sorry I'm not following your first answer, although I am sure it's accurate.

Comment: @ConnieMarie it is clear that you are using Scott’s solution, except you have not accepted his answer yet, however the method is shown in mine and your learning / understanding will be improved if you “make it fit” yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(UPPER(LEFT(A2)),{"A","K","O"}),"PM A","PM B","PM C")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your formula worked!!

I tried to repurpose it for "Second Part" (see original post, I added another picture), but have difficulty figuring this part out. If you have any solutions for the second part, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just change the last part from: `,"PM A","PM B","PM C")` to `,"Approver A","Approver B","Approver A")`

Comment: Thank you Scott! Sorry that was a dumb question! You are awesome!

Comment: Hey @Scott Craner, I just tried to add this logic:             

=IF(ISNULL(A2), " ", CHOOSE(MATCH(UPPER(LEFT(A9)),{"A","K","O"}),"Taylor, Lavelle","Russell, Margaret","Taylor, Lavelle"))                   

Basically, If A7 in your screenshot is blank, I want B7 to be blank, not #N/A.

Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: use `=IF(Trim(A2)="", "",CHOOSE(MATCH(UPPER(LEFT(A2)),{"A","K","O"}),"Taylor, Lavelle","Russell, Margaret","Taylor, Lavelle"))`  Make sure both references are to the same cell, you had A2 and A9.

Comment: @ConnieMarie please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, just a variation from the @Scott's formula, you can try:

```
=LOOKUP(LEFT(A2,1),{"A","K","O"},{"A","B","C"})
```

[image]